# bidirectional replication configuration of CouchDB/Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I use cloudant on Bluemix and want to setup continuous & bidirectional replication between 2 clusters (one is located on US-South and the other is located on EU-GB).

I check cloudant's API Docs, I understand there are 2 replications: "push" replication and "pull" replication. So when I set bidirectional replication, there are 3 patterns: Push-Push, Push-Pull, Pull-Pull (See the following picture).

[Question]
Which setting is the best, suitable, or recommended when I setup continuous & bidirectional replication? I especially want to know if there is a difference between them in terms of performance and the amount of API calls per day.

Regards,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We typically recommend Push-Push as it minimizes transactions between replicas and keeps the most up-to-date state between the two clusters. Since the replicas are between alternate datacenters, Push-Push is highly recommended.

Push-Pull and Pull-Pull would be useful in applications where you have semi-connected devices, such as mobile sync.